# mysql command as a python subprocess

Tags: python, mysql, subprocess

I want to execute the following command from python. When I run it from shell I get the desired output but calling it with subprocess I get an error.

The command is :

```
        to_date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`; mysql -uroot -p**** lportal -e "select COUNT(*) from User_ where loginDate like \"$to_date%\";" | sed 1d
```

This is my python code:

```
    from subprocess import *

    cmd='''  to_date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`; mysql -uroot -p**** lportal -e "select COUNT(*) from User_ where loginDate like \"$to_date%\";" | sed 1d  '''
    cmd_out=Popen(cmd,stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,shell=True,stderr=PIPE).communicate()
    print cmd_out
```

This is the error I get, I know it's \" relevant, but didnt figure out how to solve it.

```
    ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-04-17%' at line 1
```

Comment: Why are you doing this, instead of using a mysql library to interface directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment from @Daniel Roseman, but have you tried single quotes instead of double quotes on the SQL command? Like this:

```
select COUNT(*) from User_ where loginDate like '$to_date%';
```

Or maybe double the backslash, to escape the backslash and not the quote, on the python string...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you use?

```
`date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

Instead of:

```
import time
date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-d", time.localtime())
```

When i am doing things like this i always use this method:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'xterm -display {} -e {}'.format(display, command)
status = subprocess.call(cmd.split())
```

the command would be much cleaner to read:

```
cmd = 'mysql -u {} -p {} lportal -e "select COUNT(*) from User_ where loginDate like "{}" | sed 1d'.format(username, password, date)
```

could not test the last command since i dont have mysql here...

Hope this will help you find a solution.

---

But to be honest i would never query database like this. Daniel Roseman is totally right you should use a mysql library to achive what you want, without too much effort.